# How to do Schema validation in Core WCF

Tags: corewcf

Core WCF is new buzz in town.And support available there is limited.

I have existing webserive in framework 4.6 which i want to migrate to dot net 6 core WCF. i have having trouble with performing schema validation
Can anyone plese guide me here.

Thanks